# What is CATEGORY_INFO used for in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm learning about intents, and I can't for the life of me figure out what `CATEGORY_INFO` is used for. The docs say:

> Provides information about the package it is in; typically used if a package does not contain a `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` to provide a front-door to the user without having to be shown in the all apps list.

The only other reference I can find to `CATEGORY_INFO` on the web is in a [`PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) method called `getLaunchIntentForPackage(String)`. The info is just as much if not more obtuse:

> Returns a "good" intent to launch a front-door activity in a package. This is used, for example, to implement an "open" button when browsing through packages. The current implementation looks first for a main activity in the category `CATEGORY_INFO`, and next for a main activity in the category `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`. Returns null if neither are found.

What is a front-door activity? In what context would you not want an app to be shown in the all apps list but would want to provide a front door activity?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `CATEGORY_INFO` is an activity (screen) which displays information about that app. For example, imagine you have a soft keyboard app, or an app which only provides a widget, or an app which provides a "Live Wallpaper", something like that. Such apps may not want to appear on the "all apps" screen as the user can't actually do anything with them directly and so they just cause clutter on the "all apps" screen. However, the app may want to have an information screen that can be accessed via Google Play, to explain what that app is and how to invoke it (for example, go into settings and set this app as your default keyboard). This is basically what `CATEGORY_INFO` does. It means the activity won't appear on the "all apps" screen, but it can still be opened via Google Play ("Open" button) - and the idea is that this activity just displays some information about the app.

Answer (score -1):

I can elaborate you regarding CATEGORY_LAUNCHER.
If you are specifying CATEGORY_LAUNCHER as your intent's category, it means if your app will selected from the launcher, Activity with this category type in particular application will open. That activity will be considered as front-door activity for your application. Because whenever you are going to launch the application from launcher this activity will be shown first.

There are so many types of category available to set into activity. You can find [list of category](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) in section of standard category.

CATEGORY_INFO : It will be useful when your app has no user interface. Ex.: Live Wallpaper Application.

You will surely get your answer from [here](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-apps-info-category/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` fine. My question is about `CATEGORY_INFO`.